# Chrome (Webkit) Storage API - Unable to write to a serial port

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, serial-port, storage

I am using Storage API in chrome source code to write to a serial port on windows. I modified the code in Storage.cpp. The exact program works fine in WebKit source code. But, I am unable to create file in chrome source code (Storage.cpp is the same in both WebKit and chrome).
Here is my code snippet.

`HANDLE m_hSerialComm = CreateFile(TEXT("COM5"), GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,NULL)`;

The handle `m_hserialComm` is pointing to a junk memory location. Does Chrome have their own implementation of HANDLE? Does chrome have any restrictions in letting a program write to a serial port?